# How do I create a hard link/junction for multiple folders pointing to a single folder?

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link, hardlink, junction, directory-junction

Example:

> D:\Comp\

this directory has these folders -

> Volume 1
> Volume 2
> Volume 3

I want to point Volume 1 and Volume 2 to one folder, and Volume 3 to another such that everything looks like this:

> D:\Comp A\Volume 1\
> D:\Comp A\Volume 2\
> D:\Comp B\Volume 3\

Is this possible to do?

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem?

```bash
MKLINK /d  "D:\Comp A\Volume 1\"   X:
MKLINK /d  "D:\Comp A\Volume 2\"   X:
MKLINK /d  "D:\Comp B\Volume 3\"   Y:
```